# Multithreading Implementation in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently working on a project that I have to use Thread. For the first time I am going to use. So there are lots of problems with my code.

Firstly I am trying to test my Thread blocks whether they are working at the same time or not.

Here my test application.

```
public class sad extends Thread
{
private String name;

private Thread t1 = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            System.out.println( "I am thread 1 and working properly" );
        }
    }
};
private Thread t2 = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            System.out.println( "I am thread 2 and working properly" );
        }
    }
};

public void starter()
{
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
}
```

And button part:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            sadObj.starter();
        }
    });
```

And when I run this program:

```
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 1 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
I am thread 2 and working properly
```

This is limited version of the output. Normally there are lots of output and all of them are separate. I mean that they must work, they must print mixed. In my example they act like one by one.

In my project I have to do 2 completely diffirent task simultaneously. To achive that, I prefer to use 2 thread object. But I think that they do not run exactly same time or one of them waits for some reason. Both must be run continuously. Is my implementation wrong or, How can do that?

When I am searching Thread in java, I have seen that If the computers CPU has more then 1 core, the multithreading will work very well. My CPU is i7-3740M. It has at least 4 cores I think. So what is the problem?

Thank You 
   Best Regards

Comment: How are you using your `sad` instance?

Comment: Looks like they both have the same name and therefore print the same things. How can you tell them apart?

Comment: I have another window application which simply has one button. When I press the button, it instantiate 2 sad object with diffirent names

Comment: Threads execute in parallel, by definition. You don't need to test this. Don't test the platform. All you're doing here is exposing bugs in the test program.

Comment: Instantiating a class simply invokes the constructor of that class. It doesn't automatically call any methods. What are you doing with your 2 objects? (I hate being out of votes. I hate having to ask these questions, the explanation should already be in your question body.)

Comment: @Todd I have realized that there is a problem. But my main project not like that I mean Threads do diffirent task. So I can see when they work. But you are right in test there is problem

Comment: I have edited my question @Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: The threads run in parallel, but that does not mean that they are exactly in sync.  In fact, that's the whole issue with multithreaded programming:  the relative speeds at which the threads run are nondeterministic, so you have to write your program to handle that.

Comment: I need to have 2 Threads which are running continuously. If one of them waits a second, program will be unsuccessful

Comment: Then you need to redesign your program, or use a real time operating system and JVM.

Comment: What are real time operating system and JVM exactly

Comment: 'Real time' refers to a class of system that provides guarantees about timing. Java and conventional operating systems like Windows, UNIX, Linux, etc. don't do that. Your question here is clearly part of an XY problem. I suggest you remove this question and post your real question, about your real code and your expectations from it, and why you think the threads need to execute within one second or whatever it is.

Comment: Without this kind of system,  is it impossible to have 2 Threads which are running at the same time continuosly?

Comment: All threads run in parallel, by definition. I've already said that. The issue here is about your timing constraints, whatever they are. You need to describe your *actual problem,* in a *new question.*

Comment: I have said that my problem is that when one thread is running the other one is waiting or vice versa. By the time thanks for comments :)

Comment: You haven't proven that, for the reasons given in comments above. You haven't even shown expected and actual output from your code. Difficult to know exactly what you're talking about and whether you even have a problem at all frankly.

Comment: Sorry for insufficient explanation. This is my second question. But I have edited

Comment: _they must print mixed_ Why do you think that's how it should work? Why would your code do that?

Comment: Because they are running parallel. So why one of them waiting for another. If Thread works like one by one, why we are using it? We can handle it easily without using multithreading

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a core simulates doing several things at once by switching back and forth between single tasks very quickly.

Your system seems to be optimizing the work, by choosing not to do as much switching, allowing one task to run a lot, and another task to run a lot.  This way it doesn't switch as often (an expensive thing to do) and you get "runs" of one thread followed by "runs" of another.

You can provide a "hint" to the system that you could yield to another thread at a particular point.  It might provide the CPU with more of an excuse to switch threads.

```
private Thread t1 = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            System.out.println( "I am thread 1 and working properly" );
            this.yield();
        }
    }
};
private Thread t2 = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            System.out.println( "I am thread 2 and working properly" );
            this.yield();
        }
    }
};
```

but at the end of the day, thread scheduling is something that you don't get to fully control explicitly.

PS.  Your `sad` class doesn't need to extend Thread unless it has it's own `run()` method and is started.  In your example it doesn't.

Comment: Is this.yield() says core to switch the other thread? This is what I get from your answer. Thanks for answer by the time...

Comment: @kimdirbilmem The yeild() hints to the thread scheduler (a component you cannot control) that now would be a good time to put a different thread on the core.  It doesn't mean that the thread scheduler will do it, but it might.  It is not a direct command, just a suggestion, but if you do not suggest, then the thread will be switched out whenever the thread scheduler decides, without any input at all.